# How to look for html element with selenium and VBA within a frame

Tags: javascript, html, vba, selenium

I am trying to use selenium web driver with the driver.FindElementById"retrieve_button" in an html page, but the command could not find the element and keep giving me error. I have attached the html code in the image and the element I'm trying to find is the input element at the end of the code in the image.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That happen because the element is inside an `iframe`..

Comment: Hi Zakaria, could you give me a hint of how to find the element in the iframe, please?

Comment: What does it have to do with VBA?

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch using the function `switchToFrame`, like :

```
sel.switchToFrame "Login"  // 'Login' is the frame 'name' or 'id'.

//Then get your element 
sel.findElementById("retrieve_button")
```

Comment: I tried driver.switchToFrame("ncFrameset") but it says Frame not be found.
In the html the framset tag was used and the id is "ncFrameset".

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the error with `driver.FindElementById"retrieve_button"` as the **`WebElement`** is within an **`<iframe>`** which contains the attribute **`src`** with a value set to **`/index.cgi?top<text_not_clear_in_snapshot>`**.

You need to first switch to the **`<iframe>`** first and then find the **`WebElement`** as follows :

### Pseudo Code :

```
//SwitchTo the intended frame
driver.switchToFrame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//iframe[contains(@src,'/index.cgi?top<text_not_clear_in_snapshot>')]")))
//find the element now
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='retrieve_button']")
```

> **Note** : Ignore the **`<frameset>`** tags. They have null effect.